# Submit button to other workbook

Tags: vba, excel, export

Im making a new excel template where the managers can add info so that we can make a quote based on their template. The meaning is that if they are clicking on the submit button that depending on the value segment gos to the correct excel file (follow up list) and that the customer name, customer id and general info put in the follow up list.

This is de code that i have until now, only thing is the submit button that i need to have.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("B7") <> "Server & Storage" And Range("B7") <> "Power" And Range("B7") <> "Networking" And Range("B7") <> "Software" And Range("B7") <> "Printing" Then
        MsgBox "Selecteer een value segment!"
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
'E-mail knop
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
Dim srtEmail As String
On Error Resume Next
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xMailBody = "Hi Team," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Dit is een nieuwe request voor " & Range("B8")

If Range("B7") = "Server & Storage" Then
    srtEmail = "hardware@bechtle.be"
Else
    If Range("B7") = "Power" Then
        srtEmail = "hardware@bechtle.be"
    Else
        If Range("B7") = "Networking" Then
         srtEmail = "networking@bechtle.be"
         Else
            If Range("B7") = "Software" Then
             srtEmail = "software@bechtle.be"
              Else
                  If Range("B7") = "Printing" Then
                    srtEmail = "kristof.neubauer@bechtle.com"
                  Else
                    MsgBox "Geen value segment geselecteerd!"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
              On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail

    .To = srtEmail
    .CC = "berty.vaneijgen@bechtle.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Value Request voor " & Range("B9") & Range("B8")
    .Body = xMailBody

If Range("B7") <> "" Then
    .Display   'or use .Send
End If
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
'Reset knop
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Sheets("VRT").Range("B7:B33") = ""
  MsgBox "Velden zijn gewist!"

  End Sub
  'Save as knop
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Dim nom As String
  nom = Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & " " & Range("B8")
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & nom & ".xlsm"
   rep = MsgBox("Je bestand is opgeslagen! ", vbYes + vbInformation, "Copy  of spreadsheet")

  'MsgBox(You database has been saved  : " & Name, vbYes +         vbInformation, "Copy of spreadsheet")
 End Sub
  'print
  Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
   Cancel = (ActiveSheet.Name = "VRT")
  If Cancel = True Then MsgBox "Gebruik de print knop."

 End Sub
    'print knop
  Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
 On Error Resume Next
   Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("VRT")
            .Range("A1:F33").PrintOut
    End With
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   On Error GoTo 0
    End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can open the developer tab and create a button. [How to show developer tab on the ribbon MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx)
- Create an ActiveX button, by clicking the Developer Tab > Insert > Command Button:

[image]

- Then make sure that the name of the button is `CommandButton1`, to be compatible with your code. This is where to rename the name of the button:
  [image]

Comment: Hi, I know how to add a button and change the name of it but want to have a code or the beginning of the code to go further on it. Want to have a working button (submit button) that copy 2-3 fields of 1 workbook to an other but depending on the cell B7 beceause there are 5 diffrent segments to copy the data in the correct excel file.

Comment: @Marco187 - I read "This is de code that i have until now, only thing is the submit button that i need to have.", thus I think that you already have a code, that works?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have the code, and only need to add the button, these steps may be what you need to follow.

-Add a button from the 'Developer' tab using the Insert group

-Right-click on the button to 'Assign macro..'. You will see a list of subs 
 present in the workbook to select from.

-For the code use something like this

```
Dim src, dst as Workbook 
dst= ThisWorkbook 'Destination is your current workbook

'Define the src inside your IF-ELSE tree based on 'B7' cell value

'Use the statement below for each cell value with address in the 'Range' quotes
dst.Range("").Value= src.Range("").Value
```

Comment: No i dont have the code, i want a code that it pulls data from one workbook to the correct one depending from the choise of cell B7.

Comment: Edited the answer to give an idea of what the code may look like.